# Logging into MySQL -u root denied, sudo mysql works

Tags: mysql, sudo

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04, and have just installed MySQL using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

The root password was left empty when prompted. Accessing using

```
mysql -u root
```

produces an error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

However, when using `sudo`, it works just fine:

```
sudo mysql
# omitted welcome message
mysql> 
mysql> -- When prompting for current user:
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

Why is access denied using `mysql -u root`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command

`mysql -uroot -p`

Press **Enter**

Then it expects a password. If password is not set, then Press **Enter** again.